# WPF Desktop application MDI like/Parent-Child

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating an WPF desktop application.

Desc : One main window(Parent) for whole application which includes display, completely docked display.

"X" no. of child windows, whenever whichever child is opened, On minimizing of this child, the child should get minimized on the parent window  [Currently, it goes behind the main window]

**WHAT I NEED :** Whenever child is minimized it should not go behind, it should be minimized on parent window.

**Note :** I cannot use wpf.mdi.dll, since I have a data display on my main screen(Parent window, Display will be completely docked)

Comment: Can you try setting`ShowInTaskbar=false` on child window?

Comment: I've set Window.Topmost=true; and ShowInTaskbar=false, everything works fine, but when the child window is minimized it just goes behind the main or parent window. <br/> I just want the child to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/)(free) or [Telerik Docking](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddocking/overview2)(not free).

Comment: AvalonDock dint work for me, since all the child-windows should be made as UserControl and Auto resizing of controls doesnt happen properly on different resoultion. I just want to restrict my child window going behind the main or parent window

Answer (score 0):

After setting

```
    Owner = this;
    ShowIntaskbar=false;
```

The thing worked for me